# MySql Error Code: 1175. You are using safe update mode - Even with primary key

Tags: mysql

I have the following query:

```sql
UPDATE borsalino_db.reservations SET confirmed=if(confirmed=1, -1, 0) WHERE confirmed = 1;
```

This produces the error:

```
Error Code: 1175. You are using safe update mode and you tried to update a table without a WHERE that uses a KEY column.  To disable safe mode, toggle the option in Preferences -> SQL Editor and reconnect.
```

Only when i add

```
SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES = 0;
UPDATE borsalino_db.reservations SET confirmed=if(confirmed=1, -1, 0) WHERE confirmed = 1;
SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES = 1;
```

It works. But this seems wrong to me to do it like this. I do not want to disable safe mode.
So i tried to add `confirmed` as a primary key but still getting the error.

[image]

Any ideas on how to solve this?
Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well a work around that, is to use something that can never fail in your where clause for example:

```
WHERE confirmed = 1 AND id > 0
```

That way you will use a key column and id is always above 0 so you never gonna run into problems. It's just a work around to get over this issue but i believe that your solution is still the most common one and the most used.

To be honest i believe that your solution in your question is the real way to go but since you asked for an alternative the above way may fit you as well.

Comment: Great!! Thanks for that workaround! seems elegant! i do not know the downsides of this workaround. Why is it better removing the `safe_mode` and not always using the workaround approach?

Comment: Safe mode simply runs Update and Delete queries requiring a where clause using a key. That's pretty much it. It's not good or bad is a question of how much you need to be that strict  in what you are building. Glad that my solution worked out for you :)

Comment: what a  life hack